# What's the name of this set theory property? $(A \subseteq B) \land (B \subseteq C) \implies (A \subseteq C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, definition

What's the name of this property in set theory that states that $$(A \subseteq B) \land (B \subseteq C) \implies (A \subseteq C)?$$

Comment: Transitivity. $~$

Comment: FYI the "set theory" tag is used for more advanced topics in set theory - look at the tag descriptions.

Answer (score 5):

This is **transitivity**. In general, a binary relation $R$ is transitive iff $$x R y\wedge yRz\implies xRz.$$

---

Other key properties of binary relations you should know are **symmetry** (= $xRy\implies yRx$) and **reflexivity** (= $xRx$). A relation which is transitive, symmetric, and reflexive is called an **equivalence relation**, and this is a fundamentally important notion. A relation which is transitive and symmetric - like $\subseteq$ - is called a **partial order** (or sometimes **weak partial order** - the term "partial order" is often reserved for transitive *asymmetric* relations).

While not related to your specific question here, I think this additional terminology is worth mentioning here since you'll likely run into it soon as well.

Comment: "a relation which is transitive and symmetric", I think you mean "reflexive"? Also, just having those properties would make it a pre-order, a partial order would involve some equality axiom.